# What is the explanation behind a significant difference in the way Java and C# handle method binding?

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages, binding, language-design

In Java, the method call of an object depends solely on the object type, and not the reference type.

In C#, the reference type plays an important role in determining whether the method from the parent class is called or the method from the child class is called, based on whether the method is virtual or not.

1. Is the above statement accurate?
2. Why does Java restrict this, and does it not take away some power from the programmer?

Comment: are you talking about CoVariance and ContraVariance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is incorrect. In C# it is not based just on whether method is virtual. Even virtual methods can behave differently based on type of reference. See example below and watch at keyword **new**.

Java language is simple. It tries to stay simple. Yes, it does take away "some power" as you wrote, but in compensation you get clean code easy to understand.

C# language has more features, but sometimes you need to try hard to understand all of them. This particular example on inheritance of methods with same name is a nice example. We can create more interesting things in C#.... which nobody will understand.

Usually we cannot choose language because we are constrained by system platform, libraries and other technologies.

```
class A {
  public virtual void M1() {
    Console.WriteLine("A.M1()");
  }
}

class B : A {
  public new virtual void M1() {
    Console.WriteLine("B.M1()");
  }
}

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    b.M1();
    A a = b;
    a.M1();
  }
}
```

In C# you get two different results, although you have the same object.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought the virtual keyword prohibited this.

Comment: Why is that surprising?  You intentionally hid the M1 method by using the new keyword and thus broke any possible polymorphic behavior.  This isn't a good example of the question anyway, -1

Comment: Ed, why don't you like it? I provided that obscure example to show that the statement in the original question which says that in C# it is based on whether method is virtual or not, is in the fact incorrect. I would rather recommend not to make any simple theoretic one-sentence statements about differences of C# and Java, because you can often find some obscure example which proves your statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In Java all non-static methods are virtual, however for the static methods, the type of the reference is all that matters. For this reason it is considered bad practice to use a reference for a non-virtual static method and using the class instead is preferred.

e.g. you can write

```
Integer i = null;
int j = i.parseInt("1");
```

This won't throw an exception because not only is actual type of `i` ignored but so is its value.

It is extremely rare that you would want to call a parent's method instead of the child's method.  The developer of the child class overrode the method for a reason.  Having to imagine how your class would behave if any combination of overridden methods could be un-overriden is a headache I would rather do without.